# RTC SCM Baseline on a file

Tags: eclipse, version-control, rtc, baseline

We're using RTC/Jazz SCM and I'm the Configuration manager in our team...

So I setup the RTC/Jazz SCM, I created a component, I created a stream, I created a repository workspace and a local workspace, the repository has the stream as flow target.

After I shared an eclipse Project I did some other changes and my component grew and grew...
I made baselines whenever I made a build. Now my coworker are asking me: how can I know if my file is in this or that build, and I'm not sure how to answer their question, so

How can you show all BASELINEs on a FILE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article "[Practicing source control archaeology with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/447)" shows that a file History view only shows change set, not baselines:

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/2.0/source-control-histories/images/image002.png]

If your change set is linked to a work item, that work item id will be part of the change set title.

And it is better to consider work items instead of files, because for a given build (see [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/90893/linking-work-items-to-builds)), you can use the  "Work Items link",the one in the Contribution Summary section of a **build result**.

You can then have a look at "Work items included in this build": work items whose change sets are included in the configuration being built.

This differs from "Work items reported against this build" (top right corner of a build result), which are ones that you explicitly associate with the build (commonly, work items that created after the build was completed, that refer to information generated by this build, such as errors reported in the build results).

So there isn't a direct way, but looking at a build result can help find a work item you know your file is a part of.

---

[Scott Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387301/scott-cowan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749900/rtc-scm-baseline-on-a-file/24750998?noredirect=1#comment38416301_24750998):

> you can easily **get to a change set's work item** **to find it's build results** by:
>
> - selecting the file version in the `History view` and
> - in the context menu select "`Related Artifacts > Open`".

Comment: Thank you VonC, i'm a bit disappointed, that this feature is not availible, but you saved me a lot of 'search work'... i'm already studing your articles about archeolgy ^^  -  but thanks really, your picture showed how i can see at least my current state...

Comment: Adding to VonC's answer, you can easily get to a change set's work item to find it's build results by selecting the file version in the History view and in the context menu select "Related Artifacts > Open".

Comment: @ScottCowan good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: yes thanks for that hint Scott Cowan, weird, but some change sets are included in a build and some are not - it's weird because i know that all change set are included! (as seen on my repository work space, which is the build repository workspace)